# Program.exe has triggered a breakpoint in destructor of linked list class

Tags: c++, exception, linked-list, crash, destructor

When I run my program, everything works as expected until the destructor of the LList class. On the line that says `delete current;`, I get the following error:

`BlankConsoleLab.exe has triggered a breakpoint.`

I have been trying to solve this issue for a long time. I would appreciate it if perhaps someone could try to point out what I am doing wrong here.

Below is my code for the program. Thank you

**Linked List Class**

```
class LList
{
private:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int size = 0;
public:
    LList()
    {
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
        size = 0;
    }
    LList(Node* h, Node* t)
    {
        this->head = h;
        this->tail = t;
    }
    ~LList()
    {
        Node* current = head;
        while (current != nullptr) {
            Node* next = current->m_next;
            delete current;
            current = next;
        }
    }

    void print()
    {
        //temporary node pointer to traverse through the linked list
        Node* temp = head;

        cout << endl << "<MY LINKED LIST>\n";
        while (temp != nullptr)
        {
            cout << temp->m_data.firstName << " ";
            cout << temp->m_data.lastName << " ";
            cout << temp->m_data.hrWage << " ";
            cout << temp->m_data.hrWork << " " << endl;
            temp = temp->m_next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    void removeFirst()
    {
        //case 1: linked list is empty (never enters loop)
        //case 2: linked list is not empty
        if (head != nullptr)
        {
            Node* temp = head;
            head = head->m_next;
            delete temp;

            //decrease size tracker of the linked list
            size--;
        }
    }

    void removeLast()
    {
        //case 1: linked list is empty (never enters loop)
        //case 2: linked list has one node
        if (head->m_next == nullptr)
        {
            removeFirst();
        }
        //case 3: linked list has more than one node
        else if (head != nullptr)
        {
            Node* cur = head;
            Node* prev = nullptr;

            while (cur->m_next != nullptr)
            {
                prev = cur;
                cur = cur->m_next;
            }

            tail = prev;
            tail->m_next = nullptr;
            delete cur;
            //decrease size tracker of the linked list
            size--;
        }

    }

    //void removeAt(int pos)
    //{
    //    //Case 1: input is invalid (less than 1 or greater than size)
    //    if (pos < 1 && pos > size)
    //    {
    //        return;
    //    }
    //    //Case 2: input is position 1
    //    else if (pos == 1)
    //    {
    //        removeFirst();
    //    }
    //    //Case 3: input is the last position (input equals size)
    //    else if (pos == size)
    //    {
    //        removeLast();
    //    }
    //    //Case 4: input is valid, and not 1 or last position (greater than 1 and less than size)
    //    else if (head != nullptr)
    //    {
    //        Node* cur = head;
    //        Node* prev = nullptr;

    //        for (int i = 1; i < pos; i++)
    //        {
    //            prev = cur;
    //            cur = cur->m_next;
    //        }

    //        prev->m_next = cur->m_next;
    //        delete cur;
    //        size--;
    //    }
    //}

    Node* swap(Node* lh, Node* rh)
    {
        Node* temp = rh->m_next;
        rh->m_next = lh;
        lh->m_next = temp;

        return rh;
    }

    void readBin()
    {
        ifstream file;
        file.open("C:\\Users\\there\\source\\repos\\cst126-lab9-JEmersonLawrance\\BlankConsoleLab\\Employee Data.bin", ios::binary);

        if (file)
        {
            Node* cur = head;
            Node* prev = nullptr;

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                file.read((char*)&cur->m_data.firstName, sizeof(cur->m_data.firstName));
                file.read((char*)&cur->m_data.lastName, sizeof(cur->m_data.lastName));
                file.read((char*)&cur->m_data.hrWage, sizeof(cur->m_data.hrWage));
                file.read((char*)&cur->m_data.hrWork, sizeof(cur->m_data.hrWork));
                prev = cur;
                cur = cur->m_next;
            }
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "File could not be opened..\n" << endl;
        }

        file.close();
    }

    void writeBin()
    {
        ofstream file;
        file.open("Employee Data Output.bin", ios::binary);

        if (file)
        {
            Node* cur = head;
            Node* prev = nullptr;

            while (cur != nullptr)
            {
                file.write((char*)&cur->m_data.firstName, sizeof(cur->m_data.firstName));
                file.write((char*)&cur->m_data.lastName, sizeof(cur->m_data.lastName));
                file.write((char*)&cur->m_data.hrWage, sizeof(cur->m_data.hrWage));
                file.write((char*)&cur->m_data.hrWork, sizeof(cur->m_data.hrWork));
                prev = cur;
                cur = cur->m_next;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "File could not be opened..\n" << endl;
        }

        file.close();
    }
};
```

**Node Class**

```
class Node
{
public:
    Employee m_data;
    Node* m_next;

    Node()
    {
        m_data.firstName = "";
        m_data.lastName = "";
        m_data.hrWage = 0;
        m_data.hrWork = 0;

        m_next = nullptr;
    }
    Node(Node* next)
    {
        m_data.firstName = "";
        m_data.lastName = "";
        m_data.hrWage = 0;
        m_data.hrWork = 0;

        m_next = next;
    }
    Node(const Node& copy)
    {
        m_data.firstName = copy.m_data.firstName;
        m_data.lastName = copy.m_data.lastName;
        m_data.hrWage = copy.m_data.hrWage;
        m_data.hrWork = copy.m_data.hrWork;
    }
    Node operator = (const Node& copy)
    {
        m_data.firstName = copy.m_data.firstName;
        m_data.lastName = copy.m_data.lastName;
        m_data.hrWage = copy.m_data.hrWage;
        m_data.hrWork = copy.m_data.hrWork;

        return *this;
    }
    ~Node()
    {
    }
};
```

**Employee Class**

```
struct Employee
{
public:
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int hrWage;
    int hrWork;

    Employee()
    {
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
        hrWage = 0;
        hrWork = 0;
    }

    Employee(string first, string last, int wage, int work)
    {
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
        hrWage = wage;
        hrWork = work;
    }

    ~Employee()
    {

    }

    void getInput()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            cout << "EMPLOYEE # " << i+1 << ":\n" << endl;

            cout << "First name: ";
            cin >> this[i].firstName;
            cout << "Last name: ";
            cin >> this[i].lastName;
            cout << "Hourly Wage: ";
            cin >> this[i].hrWage;
            cout << "Hours Worked: ";
            cin >> this[i].hrWork;
        }
    }

    void writeBin()
    {
        ofstream file;
        file.open("C:\\Users\\there\\source\\repos\\cst126-lab9-JEmersonLawrance\\BlankConsoleLab\\Employee Data.bin", ios::binary);

        if (file)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                file.write((char*)&this[i].firstName, sizeof(this[i].firstName));
                file.write((char*)&this[i].lastName, sizeof(this[i].lastName));
                file.write((char*)&this[i].hrWage, sizeof(this[i]).hrWage);
                file.write((char*)&this[i].hrWork, sizeof(this[i]).hrWork);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "File could not be opened..\n" << endl;
        }

        file.close();
    }
};
```

**Main Function**

```
int main()
{
    cout << "In this program, LIST will read the user information"
        << " in from a binary file, and output it into a different binary"
        << " file.\n" << endl;

    Employee data[4];

    data->getInput();

    data->writeBin();

    //creating linked list
    Node fourth;
    Node third(&fourth);
    Node second(&third);
    Node first(&second);


    LList LIST(&first, &fourth);

    LIST.readBin();

    LIST.writeBin();

    LIST.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This: `file.read((char*)&cur->m_data.firstName, sizeof(cur->m_data.firstName));` will *never* work, assuming the `string` type you're using for `firstName` and all the `lastName` member of that class are actually `std::string`. That is not a plain data type. it cannot be memory dumped into, or out of, a file by address. It needs to be stored and reconstituted via a *protocol*. I do not know what form your "bin" file is, but it doesn't really matter in this case, because that and the subsequent `lastName` field can *NOT* be binary-read like that. It is a recipe for fail.

Comment: On a separate note, your 2nd `LList` constructor is not calculating a value for `size`. And `readBin()` should be creating new `Node`s instead of reading into pre-existing `Node`s.

Answer (score 0):

In `main()`, you are constructing your `LIST` object with pointers to local `Node` objects that are created in automatic memory within `main()`'s call frame. When `main()` exits, all of its local variables are destroyed automatically. But, when the `LIST` object is destroyed, its destructor tries to call `delete` on those `Node` objects which were not created in dynamic memory with `new`. Thus, your code exhibits *undefined behavior*.